# Need help to perform an ETL task with SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

I want to connect to a server using its IP address. Then, I want to execute a .sql file kept on that servers drive. I also want to store the results of this sql in a text file on the server itself. Should i execute it as an sql task or run it as an extraction from database or something else ? I am not sure how to go about it. I need tips on how to proceed.

The database used is SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SSIS, you can execute SQL and export it to text file(csv).

Please refer this article.
http://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/ssis-export-query-result-to-a-file/

Answer (score 0):

Creating an SSIS Solution on SQL Server to flat file.

Open Microsoft Visual Studio
Click Create Project
Select Integration Services Project
Name the Project (x2)
Set the location, example C:\SSISPackages\
Click OK

Click the Data Flow tab
Click to create a new Data Flow Task
Click the Toolbox tab (bottom left)
Drag OLE DB Source to Data Flow section
Drag Flat File Destination (for example) to Data Flow section
Drag the green arrow to connect the OLE DB Source to the Flat File Destination

Double-click OLE DB Source
Click New next to OLE DB Connection Manager
Select YOURSERVER\YOURDB and click OK
Change Data Access Mode to SQL Command
Enter procedure and parameter(s) (for example) under SQL Command Text
Click Parse Query to confirm the SQL Command is valid, and click OK

Double-click the Flat File Destination
Click New next to Flat File Connection Manager
Choose Ragged Right (if standard fixed-width with CR/LF at end of each row) and click OK
Click Browse and select the destination and file name for the output and click OK twice
Click on Mappings and confirm the input and destination columns are correct, and click OK

To append the current date to the file name:
Click on Package Explorer tab (top right of center pane)
Click on Variables tab (bottom left)
Add a variable called path, Scope = Package, Data Type = String, Value = path to file (not including YYYYMMDD.txt portion of file name)

In the Properties for Flat File Connection Manager (bottom center, right-click), open Expressions, and set Property to ConnectionString and Expression to:

```
@[User::path]+
(DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("yyyy",getdate()) +
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("m",getdate()),2) +
Right("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252) DatePart("d",getdate()),2) + ".txt"
```

(Or however you need the date and file name formatted)

Click Evaluate Expression to make sure it looks OK.